# Define a numerical polymorphic module

Tags: module, ocaml

I would like to define a module which could support `int`, `int64` and `float`. For instance,

```
module Matrix =
  struct
    type 'a t = 'a array array

    (* add point-wise 2 matrices with same dimension *)
    let add (m: 'a t) (n: 'a t): 'a t =
      ...
  end
```

The implementation of `add` needs the operator `plus`, which is `+` for `int`, `+.` for `float` and `Int64.add` for `int64`. So I can't write anyone of them, otherwise, the type of `Matrix` is no more polymorphic.

Could anyone tell me how you work around this problem?

One idea I have at the moment is to make the `Matrix` a functor:

```
module type NUM_TYPE =
  sig
    type t
    val add: t -> t -> t
  end

module Matrix =
  functor (Elt: NUM_TYPE) 
    struct
      type element = Elt.t
      type t = element array array

      (* add point-wise 2 matrices with same dimension *)
      let add (m: t) (n: t): t =
      ...
  end
```

Then I have to define the following numerical modules:

```
module MyInt =
  (struct 
     type t = int 
     let add (a: t) (b: t): t = a + b
  end: NUM_TYPE)       

module MyFloat = ...
module MyInt64 = ...

module MatInt = Matrix(MyInt)
module MatFloat = Matrix(MyFloat)
module MatInt64 = Matrix(MyInt64)
```

By this method, I find it is tedious to define `MyInt`, `MyFloat` and `MyInt64`, especially their own `add` function. Does anyone have any idea to improve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write each of those in one line like this:

```
module MatInt = Matrix(struct type t = int let add = (+) end)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do much better in OCaml (have a look at this blog post: https://ocaml.janestreet.com/?q=node/37). This would be a very nice use of typeclasses. If you're ok with using language extensions you can have a look at this project: https://github.com/jaked/deriving.